# load cached image in jquery live event handler?

Tags: jquery, image, load, live, caching

I've read various workarounds for jQuery's load method not firing on cached images (resetting src, using .complete). But I'm having trouble actually implementing them on the following `live` event.  The cached images still don't load.

```
    $('img.img-thumbs').live('click', function() {
        $('#loader').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).empty();
            $(this).removeClass().addClass("loading visible");
            $(this).fadeIn(500);                      
        });                
        var url = ($(this).attr('src')).replace("thumbs", "content");
        var _img = new Image();
        $(_img).one("load", function() {
            $('#loader').fadeOut(500, function() {
                $(this).removeClass().addClass("loaded visible fadeMe").append($(_img));
                $(this).fadeIn(500);
            });
        }).attr('src', url);
    });
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this little plugin? —

https://gist.github.com/797120/7176db676f1e0e20d7c23933f9fc655c2f120c58 (originally: https://github.com/peol/jquery.imgloaded/)

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer. But the problem disappeared after changing the page layout.  Don't think I can be bothered to figure out why, just now.